# AWS amplify don't deploy build infinit

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, build, aws-amplify

I have a project to react to and I want to deploy it on AWS Amplify, locally I run the build perfectly, but when I do it on AWS it is compiling infinitely until I get a time out error. What am I doing wrong? I'm new to it and I couldn't find anything related

````
2020-12-30T21:20:07.282Z [WARNING]: 
2020-12-30T21:20:07.288Z [INFO]: added 2085 packages from 1294 contributors and audited 2098 packages in 31.209s
2020-12-30T21:20:08.604Z [INFO]: 96 packages are looking for funding
                                 run `npm fund` for details
2020-12-30T21:20:08.605Z [INFO]: found 1 low severity vulnerability
                                 run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
2020-12-30T21:20:08.633Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
                                 # Executing command: npm run build
2020-12-30T21:20:08.801Z [INFO]: > monetiz-web@0.1.0 build /codebuild/output/src941862754/src/monetiz-app
                                 > node scripts/build.js
2020-12-30T21:20:09.455Z [INFO]: Creating an optimized production build...
2020-12-30T21:21:08.746Z [INFO]: Compiled successfully.
```
Build Settings

```
    version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm install
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
        - node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: /build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```
````

Comment: What commands are you actually running? You say "when I do it on AWS" - have you setup amplify, added hosting and are you doing amplify publish?